# When does the function mapping a string to its prefix-free Kolmogorov complexity halt?

Tags: computability, terminology, kolmogorov-complexity, descriptive-complexity

In *Algorithmic Randomness and Complexity* from Downey and Hirschfeldt, it is stated on page 129 that

$\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{K(\sigma)\downarrow} 2^{-K(\sigma)} \leq 1$,

where $K(\sigma)\downarrow$ means that $K$ halts on $\sigma$, $\sigma$ being a binary string. $K$ denotes the prefix-free Kolmogorov complexity.

When does $K$ halt? I think it only halts on a finite number of inputs, since the classical proof on non-computability of the Kolmogorov complexity gives an upper bound on the domain of $K$. But then, the finite set of inputs on which $K$ halts can be chosen arbitrary (one just needs to store the finite number of complexities in the source code).

So is this sum well-defined? In other words, is the domain of $K$ well defined?

Comment: as commented in Raphael's answer below if $K$ is the *prefix-free* Kolmogorov complexity then it is a *partial* function (it is not defined on strings that are not prefix-free); so I think that the sum is well defined and $K(\sigma)\downarrow$ simply means "$K(\sigma)$ is defined" (i.e. $\sigma$ is a prefix-free string).

Comment: @Vor: This is certainly another valid interpretation (given the information we have). You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Raphael: ok, posted as an answer; if I find the book I'll give it a look.

Comment: @Vor [This](http://www-2.dc.uba.ar/materias/azar/bibliografia/Downey2010AlgorithmicRandomness.pdf) seems to be some early(?) version of the book. The claim of the OP didn't catch my eye, maybe it's on a different page or doesn't even exist in this early version.

Comment: @Juho: see Counting Theorem and Definition 6.7.5 (page 103) where it is shown that $K$ is equal (up to a costant) to the minimal information content measure

Comment: I went to my office to look at the book and I cannot find this on page 129. However, because $K$ is defined in terms of a universal machine on page 124, $K(\sigma)$ is defined for every string $\sigma$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: you are right, $K$ is total; so (according to my interpretation) $\sum_{K(\sigma)\downarrow} = \sum_{K(\sigma)}$ (I deleted my answer which is wrong)

Comment: This claim is not explicit in the book : they define an **information content measure** and then claim without proof that $K$ is an information content measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right; $K$ is a specific function which can not be computed. The author likely means to use *some* (arbitrary) approximative implementation; so no, this does not seem to be well-defined, if you are pedantic. You can also call it abuse of notation.

Consider this instead:

$\qquad \displaystyle \forall {M \in \mathcal{M}_K}.\ \sum_{M(\sigma)\downarrow} 2^{-K(\sigma)} \leq 1$

with $\mathcal{M}_K = \{M\ \mathrm{TM} \mid M(\sigma)\!\downarrow\ \implies\ M(\sigma)=K(\sigma) \}$ the set of all Turing machines that compute subfunctions of $K$.

In essence, this means: the bound holds no matter for which strings your implementation can compute the Kolmogorov complexity.

---

As Carl notes in the comments, it is plausible that the notation has nothing to do with halting or computing, as $K$ is not computable. Read $\sum_{K(\sigma)\!\downarrow}$ as sum ranging over the domain of $K$.

Comment: I seriously doubt this is what they meant. The $\downarrow$ notation for a partial function has nothing to do with halting, in general, it just means the partial function is defined.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I have seen the notation for both things. In particular in the realm of partially-computable functions, undefinedness and nontermination are usually equivalent.

Comment: That's true, they are equivalent in that special case. But $K$ is not partial computable, so that special case can't apply here. In fact $K$ is total, although not computable.

Comment: I think you're right, Carl, it might be the correct answer.